# Keyboard covering react-native-elements input

Tags: react-native, react-native-elements

I am using the "Input" component from react-native-elements, not "TextInput". I need to focus scroll to the input when it is touched. The keyboard keeps covering the input even after using KeyboardAwareScrollView and KeyboardAvoidingView. Please help.